# Physical significance of singular matrix in two port network

Tags: network, port, matrix

In class we've been introduced to two port networks, and I was wondering: Is there a physical significance to a singular matrix in a two port network, or is it simply where the mathematical model breaks down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean that the model breaks down, but it is usually a symptom that the model is idealized.

Consider the simplified common-emitter AC model for a BJT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA1CnI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is clear that:

\begin{align*}
   I_2 &= h_{fe} \cdot I_1 \\
   V_1 &= h_{ie} \cdot I_1
\end{align*}

which can be rewritten in matrix form as:

\$
  \begin{bmatrix} V_1 \\ I_2 \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix} 
h_{11} & h_{12} \\
h_{21} & h_{22}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix} I_1 \\ V_2 \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix} 
h_{ie} & 0 \\
h_{fe} & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{bmatrix} I_1 \\ V_2 \end{bmatrix}
\$

from which you can see the h-parameter matrix is singular, having the second column made up of zeroes, but still the model is valid, although really idealized, since it neglects the output conductance \$h_{oe}\$ and the \$h_{re}\$ coefficient.